# Create 2D panoramas from 3D image

Tags: computer-vision

Given a 3D greyscale image (particularly a dental scan) I have localized a jaw on it, i.e. made jaw's voxel intensity values much higher than others. Using this, how can I create a 2D panoramas from that 3D image? I have tried reduce_max across axis but results are far from perfect. Is there a better approach? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  Note that coding questions and requests for APIs/code/libraries are off-topic here.  I'm not sure about "reduce_max across axis" refers to.

Comment: @D.W. By reduce_max I meant projecting 3D image on, say, XY plane by taking maximum value across Z axis. I'm looking for approaches/algorithms/references.